# Warning if rebasing a branch that's been pushed to remote?

Tags: git, warnings, rebase

Is there any way to get `git` to warn you if you attempt to rebase a branch that's already been pushed?  (i.e. in the case where you're likely to be "rewriting history".)

(I realise that in some cases `git` isn't going to know whether you're rewriting history or not, but often (typically?) it will have this information.)

Comment: Isn't a `push` of a rebased branch going to be rejected anyway and always has to be `--forced`?

Comment: @pmr I'm not sure, I guess that's possible but I'd like to know before getting into that situation!

Answer (score 4):

You can use git's `pre-rebase` hook to produce a warning or error in that situation.  (The documentation for [the various `githooks` is here](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html).)  The [sample `pre-rebase` hook](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-rebase.sample) does something very similar to what you want, although (as http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks points out) you'll need to change the branch name `next` to whatever your published branch is called.

It's probably also worth pointing out (as [pmr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105672/pmr) mentions in a comment above) that if you've rewritten public history, then attempting to push that rewritten branch will not succeed - you'll get an error to avoid just this problem.

Furthermore, you should know that you can usually safely do:

```
git rebase <upstream-remote-tracking-branch>
```

For example, if you're working on the `master` branch, and its upstream remote-tracking branch is `origin/master`, then:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

... will only consider reapplying commits **that aren't contained in `origin/master`**, and that remote-tracking branch is updated when you push to `master` in `origin` as well as when you fetch from `origin`.  (The reason I say "usually" above is that this is more complicated if you're using multiple remotes, or you've set up remote-tracking branches in an unusual way.)